# не получается забилдить игру на андроид

Tags: c#, unity3d

сделал бета версию игры, хочу проверить как работает на телефоне, нажимаю билд и вылазиет Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details. See the Console for details.
ошибки в консоли:

```
> Task :launcher:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:mergeDebugNativeDebugMetadata NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:writeDebugAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:extractDeepLinksDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:checkDebugAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileDebugLibraryResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:extractDeepLinksDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:parseDebugLocalResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:processDebugMainManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:processDebugManifestForPackage UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:compileDebugShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateDebugRFile UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:checkDebugDuplicateClasses UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:desugarDebugFileDependencies UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:mergeExtDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:validateSigningDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:writeDebugAppMetadata UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:writeDebugSigningConfigVersions UP-TO-DATE

> Task :unityLibrary:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
30 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 29 up-to-date

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)

потом еще
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
G:\unity\projectsunity\Alex Fell On An Apple\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\Mono2x\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\java\com\unity\androidnotifications\UnityNotificationManager.java:165: error: cannot find symbol
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU)
                                                        ^
  symbol:   variable TIRAMISU
  location: class VERSION_CODES
G:\unity\projectsunity\Alex Fell On An Apple\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\Mono2x\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\java\com\unity\androidnotifications\UnityNotificationManager.java:166: error: cannot find symbol
            permissionGranted = mContext.checkCallingOrSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                                                                                         ^
  symbol:   variable POST_NOTIFICATIONS
  location: class permission
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
2 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':unityLibrary:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 749ms

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)

и еще
CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. 
G:\unity\2022.3.10f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\OpenJDK\bin\java.exe -classpath "G:\unity\2022.3.10f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-7.2.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m" "assembleDebug"

Environment Variables:
USERDOMAIN = TERMINATOR
ProgramFiles = C:\Program Files
TMP = C:\Users\skarg\AppData\Local\Temp
PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE = AMD64
PROCESSOR_REVISION = b701
OneDriveConsumer = C:\Users\skarg\OneDrive
OS = Windows_NT
CHROME_CRASHPAD_PIPE_NAME = \\.\pipe\crashpad_12040_WQHZHJWNWCCMHSUZ
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER = Intel64 Family 6 Model 183 Stepping 1, GenuineIntel
AMPLITUDE_API_KEY = 28f3cae0b33b8b3702120c9ed1a935aa
USERPROFILE = C:\Users\skarg
JAVA_HOME = G:\unity\2022.3.10f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\OpenJDK
CommonProgramFiles = C:\Program Files\Common Files
DriverData = C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\DriverData
ComSpec = C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
LAUNCH_DARKLY_CLIENT_TOKEN = 60a7e30fafc7e60e33446283
PSModulePath = C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules
EFC_35656 = 1
SystemRoot = C:\Windows
HEAP_CLIENT_TOKEN = 1717415662
NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS = 20
WOOTRIC_CLIENT_TOKEN = NPS-aa8be4c3
JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS = -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
DEBUG_ENV_VAR = UnityHub
ProgramW6432 = C:\Program Files
FPS_BROWSER_APP_PROFILE_STRING = Internet Explorer
OPENSSL_ia32cap = 0x20000000
TEMP = C:\Users\skarg\AppData\Local\Temp
Path = C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Users\skarg\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;
USERNAME = skarg
COMPUTERNAME = TERMINATOR
USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE = TERMINATOR
PATHEXT = .COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
SystemDrive = C:
ALLUSERSPROFILE = C:\ProgramData
SENTRY_ACCESS_TOKEN = 3df78d9e53f8456aa90fbae044ce1a6261421ab1d0014674bc2e933477289017
HEAP_CLIENT_TOKEN_STAGING = 3786794399
FPS_BROWSER_USER_PROFILE_STRING = Default
windir = C:\Windows
AMPLITUDE_API_KEY_STAGING = 83ee04fccc67e4fcc7dd527c4c6f1e21
PUBLIC = C:\Users\Public
CommonProgramFiles(x86) = C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
APPDATA = C:\Users\skarg\AppData\Roaming
PROCESSOR_LEVEL = 6
CommonProgramW6432 = C:\Program Files\Common Files
ProgramFiles(x86) = C:\Program Files (x86)
SESSIONNAME = Console
LOGONSERVER = \\TERMINATOR
LOCALAPPDATA = C:\Users\skarg\AppData\Local
HOMEPATH = \Users\skarg
LAUNCH_DARKLY_CLIENT_TOKEN_STAGING = 60a7e30fafc7e60e33446282
HOMEDRIVE = C:
OneDrive = C:\Users\skarg\OneDrive
ProgramData = C:\ProgramData
ORIGINAL_XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP = undefined


stderr[
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
G:\unity\projectsunity\Alex Fell On An Apple\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\Mono2x\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\java\com\unity\androidnotifications\UnityNotificationManager.java:165: error: cannot find symbol
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU)
                                                        ^
  symbol:   variable TIRAMISU
  location: class VERSION_CODES
G:\unity\projectsunity\Alex Fell On An Apple\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\Mono2x\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\java\com\unity\androidnotifications\UnityNotificationManager.java:166: error: cannot find symbol
            permissionGranted = mContext.checkCallingOrSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                                                                                         ^
  symbol:   variable POST_NOTIFICATIONS
  location: class permission
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
2 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':unityLibrary:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 749ms
]
stdout[
> Task :launcher:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:mergeDebugNativeDebugMetadata NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:writeDebugAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:extractDeepLinksDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:checkDebugAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileDebugLibraryResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:extractDeepLinksDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:parseDebugLocalResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:processDebugMainManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:processDebugManifestForPackage UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:compileDebugShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateDebugRFile UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:checkDebugDuplicateClasses UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:desugarDebugFileDependencies UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:mergeExtDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:validateSigningDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:writeDebugAppMetadata UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:writeDebugSigningConfigVersions UP-TO-DATE

> Task :unityLibrary:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
30 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 29 up-to-date
]
exit code: 1
UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <eb865e8041b4430e8b16e0e96097bf17>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <eb865e8041b4430e8b16e0e96097bf17>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.String command, System.String args, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <eb865e8041b4430e8b16e0e96097bf17>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools.RunJava (System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.Action`1[T] progress, System.String error) (at <eb865e8041b4430e8b16e0e96097bf17>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, Unity.Android.Gradle.AndroidGradle androidGradle, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at <eb865e8041b4430e8b16e0e96097bf17>:0)
Rethrow as GradleInvokationException: Gradle build failed
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, Unity.Android.Gradle.AndroidGradle androidGradle, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at <eb865e8041b4430e8b16e0e96097bf17>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildGradleProject.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <eb865e8041b4430e8b16e0e96097bf17>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <eb865e8041b4430e8b16e0e96097bf17>:0)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)
```

очень прошу помощи.